# Div tags jumps out of its normal flow

Tags: html, css

I am new to web designing and I am currently designing a website for my college project.Right now, I am facing a problem which is as follow:-

When I resize the browser window,specially when i resize the browser window to a small size, the div elements jumps out of it's normal flow and everything gets scattered on giving width:100% value in my container id of CSS.

But as as i give the width of the wrapper id in pixels(say 960px), everything works and looks fine. But i want to design a full width browser window website so that it can adjust on any browser window size Please tell me how it can be done.

jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/9BuHt/3/

My CSS code is as under:-

I am new to web designing and I am currently designing a website for my college project. Right now, I am facing a problem which is as follows:

When I resize the browser window, specially when I resize the browser window to a small size, the div elements jumps out of its normal flow and everything gets scattered on giving width:100% value in my container id of CSS.

But as as I give the width of the wrapper id in pixels(say 960px), everything works and looks fine. But I want to design a full width browser window website so that it can adjust on any browser window size. Please tell me how it can be done. My CSS code is as follows:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #e9e5e5;
}
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#container {
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1400px;
}
#header {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
#logo {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}
#header #title_panel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 25px;
  min-width: 60px;
}
#header #title_panel h1 {
  color: #125ab4;
  font-size: 36px;
}
#header #title_panel p {
  color: #f5071d;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}
#search_panel {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 80px;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  position: relative
}
#search_panel img {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#search_field, #usrnam_field, #pwd_field {
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #999;
  padding-left: 4px;
s
}
#login_panel {
  float: right;
  width: 520px;
  margin: 10px 200px 0px 0px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
#login_btn, #signup_btn {
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #125ab4;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
 .
}
#login_btn {
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#signup_btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header h3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: #125ab4;
}
#sidebar {
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 136px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border: solid 1px #999999;
  background: #FFF;
}
#sidebar_header {
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #009933;
}
#sidebar_header h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
#sidebar_header img {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
#sidebar ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#sidebar ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #009933;
}
#sidebar ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: #009933;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

And the html code is as under:-

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>App Store-The one stock shop for all</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" width="100" height="100" alt="logo"></div>
    <div id="title_panel">
      <h1>App Store</h1>
      <p>The one stock shop for all</p>
    </div>
    <div id="search_panel">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="search" type="text" value="Search..." id="search_field">
      </form>
      <img src="images/Search_icon.png" width="22" height="22" alt="SearchIcon"> </div>
    <div id="login_panel">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="usrname" type="text" value="Username" size="30" id="usrnam_field">
        <input name="psswrd" type="text" value="Password" size="30" id="pwd_field">
      </form>
      <a href="#">
        <div id="login_btn">Login</div>
      </a>
      <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
      <h3>Not a member yet?</h3>
        <a href="#">
      <div id="signup_btn"> Signup</div>
      </a> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar_header"> <img src="images/logo_small.png" width="22" height="28" alt="logoIcon">
      <h2 style="">Store</h2>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Technologies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Developers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Apps</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML and CSS code here.

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Are you able to post a JSFiddle with an example of the issue?  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I have posted the code.My website is currently offline. So, i can't post the links.

Comment: You have an extra closing </div> at the end.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where you need to specifically fix small browser windows(this just might be one of them)

```
.myClass {
   width: 50%;
}
```

but at small sizes, 50% is not big enough and we make it 100%

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .myClass {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

so when the browser window is less than 600px, we fix it.

here are common device sizes http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

### EDIT

after creating an html file of the code and looking at it, it looks like you have a 100% header with some floating elements in it.

under that you have a float left sidebar.

2 fixes that make it look a bit better are:

`clear: both;` on your `#sidebar`

and use `max-width` instead of `width` on your `login_panel`

so `clear: both` will make sure that it accounts for any element floating left or right.

`max-width` means that the `login_panel` won't get too big when the screen is huge, but when the screen it small, it won't go off-screen.

Comment: Hi sir, Thanx for contributing your precious time to ansmer my question.Can u please send your email id so that i can mail you the layout page of my project so that you can understand my problem clearly and help me out...

Comment: Here's the link for jsfiddle of my project.Try changing the width of the wrapper from 1400px to 100% and see what happens and do tell me it's solution please---------          http://jsfiddle.net/9BuHt/

Comment: m trying what u said sir ....please do tell me by actually applying it on jsfiddle. I am sorry if i am bothering u.But i really need to learn all this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9BuHt/3/  Like I said in my edit, adding those 2 css rules will allow your content to flow better.  Floating is tricky.  If something is floated right, the next content item will shove itself in weird ways unless it is also floated right, or clears right. `clear:both` and also [clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) is popular.  you might want to clearfix your header and not worry about `clear: both` on your sidebar

Comment: m trying to apply these 2 things but still can't get anything. If u have time, could u please tell me by applying on it directly..

Answer (score 0):

As I correctly understand you. You are need to create a fluid markup for any device support. So look to my example and try to adapt your code the same way.

So, for example you need #wrapper width = 960px for desktops and full sized content on mobile devises (if device width < 960px). So your code must be:

**HTML**

```
#wrapper {
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden // if you have float elements inside wrapper
}
```

If you have a question - welcome